# Is ASP.NET web service replaced by WCF web service?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I don't see any template to write asp.net web service in Visual Stuido 2010. I am wondering it is replaced by WCF web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WCF service application`, some attributes are changed like `WebMethod` is`OperationContract` here

**Edit:** for soap binding:

```
<services>
  <service name="Service1">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService1"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: deos WCF service still use SOAP?

Comment: @user496949, It can be over HTTP, TCP, pipe default is HTTP and uses SOAP

Comment: @user496949: WCF can use both SOAP and REST - your choice

Answer (score 2):

You can still create old asmx web services in Visual Studio 2010. When adding a new item in a Web Site/Web Application, you should see "Web Service" under the web templates.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Microsodft are intending to replace .asmx with wcf (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448472/wcf-vs-asmx-web-service) post) but the .asmx template is still available in VS2010 under the web menu at the bottom.