# What is difference between SOAP and WCF android

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between WCF Services and Web Services and REST Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503851/difference-between-wcf-services-and-web-services-and-rest-service)

I have android application which is fetching the data from the online server, using .net web service. Up to now I used a SOAP method to get the data by send the Input XML and getting the Output XML. The received XML will be parsed using the DOM parser. Use KSOAP library.

Now the Web service has been change to Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). Here how can i send the request and How will be the responds. What library file should i use. I have some confusion with this. I know the only difference between SOAP and WCF, WCF is faster then SOAP. Can anyone clear my doubt.

Comment: Look at here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503851/difference-between-wcf-services-and-web-services-and-rest-service

Comment: WCF is a Microsoft technology stack.  It uses SOAP.  I would imagine that KSOAP would be fine to use with the WCF service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I recommend not to change your Andoid coding which is already tested and working with Websevices.

WCF is technique to bring remoting technology under one hood.WCF is a combined features of Web Service, Remoting, MSMQ and COM+. WCF provides a common platform for all .NET communication. So you can do all the same thing that you do with web-services.

Build WCF services that produce the same XML so you need not change the coding on android side and you are good to continue with WCF instead WS.

Comment: But how can i give parameters to WCF? i tried the same as soap but got an internal error

Answer (score 1):

WCF is just a communication technology from Microsoft stack that uses SOAP in most cases.

First of all post here more details about WCF sevice, e.g. Bindings used. You can continue to use KSOAP. And when service contract wasn't changed then changes to client not needed.