# Returning an ArrayList from an ASMX Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a couple of questions regarding Web Services, and I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

In my class library, I have a two classes: Hotel & RoomType.
Hotel class contains an ArrayList of RoomType objects.

In my Web Service, I have a GetHotels method as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Hotel))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(RoomType))]
public ArrayList GetHotels()
{
    return Sistema.GetInstance().GetHotels();
}
```

GetHotels() in class Sistema, retrieves the information from the database and returns an ArrayList.

I had to use XMLInclude because I was getting:

> The type Hotel (or RoomType) was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically

Then in my Web app I have this code:

```
WebService sample = new Service();
ArrayList hotels = service.GetHotels();
```

This doesn't compile, so I had to change to the following code:

```
WebService sample = new Service();
object[] hotels = service.GetHotels();
```

Here's my first question: **Is it possible to return an ArrayList, or every time I will have to cast the result to an ArrayList?**

Knowing that the ArrayList contains Hotel objects, I added the following code:

```
foreach (Hotel hotel in hotels)
{
    ...        
}
```

This compiles, but when I execute, I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode[]' to type 'Hotel'.

So, my next question is: **How can I cast the result to a Hotel object and work with it?**

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Why are you using ArrayList instead of a generic collection? Why are you using ASMX instead of WCF?

Comment: .NET 3.5. I'm using ArrayList and ASXML because I find it more comfortable to work with. Are there any disadvantages in using ASMX instead of WCF? Thanks

Comment: Aside from the fact that ASMX is a legacy technology that is kept around only for backwards compatibility, WCF is about 10 times as powerful as ASMX. It is the _replacement_ for ASMX. You're not doing your career much good by remaining "comfortable". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448472/wcf-vs-asmx-web-service

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. I'll take a look at the post you provided. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex objects are converted into simple objects when pass through SOAP.

I suggest to use this List<> in your Web Service

```
public List<Hotel> GetHotels()
{
  return ...;
}
```

so when you will call the method you'll have an Array of Hotel

```
Hotel[] hotels = service.GetHotels();
```

and then you will write

```
foreach (Hotel hotel in hotels)
{
...        
}
```

Comment: Hi Emanuele. I tried what you suggested, but I get the following compilation error in the line Hotel[] hotels = service.GetHotels() - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'Hotel[]'."

Comment: @Gonzalo how did you create the reference to that web service?

Comment: Right click on App_WebReferences > Add Web Reference. Then I typed the URL and selected Add Reference.

Comment: My solution should work.. are you shure you published web service and refreshed the reference? Can you rename the method to GetHotels1 to be shure?

Comment: You should not use web references unless necessary. Use a service reference.

Answer (score 6):

Neither `ArrayList` nor any other type specific to .NET will ever be passed across the wire from a web service. Web services only speak XML.

See [Basics: How Web Services Work](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/basics-how-web-services-work/) for more details.

In this particular case, `ArrayList` is being treated like `object[]`, which means: "an arbitrary number of some kind of object". The only way to handle that in SOAP XML is to treat it like an array of some kind of XML Node, hence `XmlNode[]`.

Answer (score 1):

### Technique - 1 to avoid type casting

```
dynamic hotels = service.GetHotels();
foreach (Hotel str in d)
{
   //Your Code
}
```

---

### Technique - 2 to avoid type casting

```
var hotels = service.GetHotels();
foreach (Hotel str in d)
{
   //Your Code
}
```