# C# WebMethod retuen List<Object>

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-serialization, webmethod

I want to return List in my web method like below,

```
public List<Object> MyMethod(){

List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
myClass a = new myClass();
list.Add(a);

return list;
```

}

```
public class myClass{
public int StudetNumber {get; set;}
public string StudentName {get; set;}
public decimal average {get; set;}
}
```

But i get this error :
System.InvalidOperationException : myClass is not expected.
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(string name, string ns, Object o , Boolean xsiType);

I don't get the error when it returns List of myClass. It is possible to return List of System.Object or Do I have to return List of myClass ?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: show us your 'myClass' type

Comment: @John I edited the question

Comment: I have just tested your code and seems to work fine... You are just missing a ";" next to "set" in your myClass class.. Take a look to this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/dbaro4

Comment: Is your `myClass` class decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute?

Comment: are you coding in notepad by any chance? :-}

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes it is

Comment: @BrankVictoria Hi, i'm still getting the error :(

Comment: myClass needs the keyword `class` or `struct`

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Updated bu still getting error

Comment: Now it is unclear to me,  you sid that you want to return a list. But then you just said "I don't get the error when it returns List. It is possible to return List or Do I have to return List ?" It is not that clear to me when the error appears.

Comment: What error do you get then? The previous code would result in a compiler error..

Comment: @BrankVictoria Ok, I mean I want to return list of System.Object. When i try it, i get the error written in question. But when i return list of MyClass i don't get the error. It is possible to return List of System.Object or am i able to return a only specified type object like myClass in Webmethods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I understand now your question. It seems that it is not compatible returning a generic type such as "Object" or `List<Object>` in a web method, because in a web method you'll have an XML definition (WSDL) and there is no way to define a generic type in that definition. So it seems that you need to always return a defined class, in your case "myClass".

Take a look to the following post where this topic was talked so it would be a little bit more clear for you:

[How do I return a C# web service that has a generic property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039391/how-do-i-return-a-c-sharp-web-service-that-has-a-generic-property)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the reserved word 'class' in your class definition
you are missing a few ';'s

```
  public class myClass
    {
        public int StudetNumber { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public decimal average { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but i wrote the question in mobile phone and i forgot the things you sad :) Normally in project myClass is the like you wrote above.