# WCF or Web Service or?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am assigned to a task where I will develop a .Net Web Service. The web service will be used by another ERP provider in order to send invoices and several tranactions from their ERP system to our ERP system. The ERP System that I am going to pass those data is using MSSQL Server database. So, practically I will have to write several hundred thousands of records to a MSSQL Server with this web service every day.

I would love to hear your advices to this approach.
1) WCF or Web Service?
2) Risks in regard of the frequency of data transfers?
3) Best approach would be?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448472/wcf-vs-asmx-web-service

Answer (score 2):

.NET Web Services (ASMX) uses Soap over HTTP in IIS.  WCF Services is far more extensible and can use lots of data formats (json/text/xml) over lots of protocols (http/tcp/mq) hosted wherever you want (IIS/Window Service/any .net app)

So I'd got with WCF for future proofing and compatibility with other providers.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding handling huge amounts of transactions, do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: You'll only be limited by the resources your server/database can provide. I wouldn't expect WCF itself to be a bottle neck