# WCF, XML WebService, Legacy Techonology

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, legacy

So I am about to create a XML webservice where I send an XML form from the client to the server in ASP.net. While looking at how to do it I see that we have to use WCF to create  [XML webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7hs6sw69%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So the question is do I need to use WCF for now on? Or can I still create the XML webservice without using WCF. Which way is better? I am using .NET framework 4.5. Is there another option that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jump to [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448568)

Personally, I would prefer WCF (*the "new" way*) over ASMX (*the "old" way - ref: the link you provided to the MSDN site*)

Comment: This means that later on ASMX will deprecated?

Comment: Not, yet. At some point in the future, maybe. I see ASMX as .NETs first good attempt on web-services. Then they learned a lot and created a new framework (WCF) for common communication mechanisms. Features are added for every new version of WCF. ASMX and WCF web services are quite similar in construction, especially if you go With the "default" settings that will bring you quite close to be compatible With ASMX web services. In other Words, the transition is not that hard. Good Luck :)