# Migrate VS2010 to VS2013 - what would be the major changes we would be facing?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, clr, visual-studio-2013

I have one web application in **`C#`** which is developed using **`Visual Studio 2010`**  and I want to convert or Migrate that web application in **`Visual Studio 2013 (C#)`**.

**Note:- Below listed things I used in my current Web Application using VS2010 (C#)**

- Asp.Net Server Controls.
- ClassLibrary (.dll).
- Web services.
- Above Listed things I used in my current Web application which is in VS2010.

**Now, My Question Is-** What would be the major changes I would be facing if I am using all above listed Microsoft Technologies using **C#** and Migrate it to VS2013.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest change for us was that Visual Studio Setup Project was depreciated in VS 2012, so we had to build new installers.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/15/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-2013-and-installshield-limited-edition.aspx

Also, which version of .NET is you application? Keep in mind framework targeting for Visual Studios (basically if your application is .NET 3.5 SP 1 or newer you should be fine):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn250998.aspx

The Web Services should also be okay, if you intend to keep creating web services instead of switching to WCF, you may want to look at this:

[Create a asmx web service in C# using visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281144/create-a-asmx-web-service-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: I want to know the issue which we find at code level and environment level

Comment: You shouldn't really have any issues at code level as you reference .NET which means the assemblies are the same throughout every version of visual studio that supports .NET X.X. Also you can get the old installers working with this VS installer https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d It made mine work which were origonally created in VS2005 so should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The thing we first noticed is VS2013 uses IIS Express 8.0, at the time our production web server was IIS 6 - we encountered, on numerous occasions a web.config setting working fine locally but forgot to add the IIS 6 equivalent.

For our web apps we kept targeting the same .Net framework  and I can't recall any issues. For your reference our stack was Asp.Net MVC 4, EF 5 WebApi plus numerous NuGet packages. So we didn't have any asp.net server controls.

You may also want to ensure all your VS2010 plugins have a 2013 equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problem at all with the types of proyects you are using.

You could even open the solution with VS2013 and then open it back with VS2010 SP1 without any problem (as long as you don't switch the .NET framework to 4.5).
Starting from VS2012, Microsoft made changes to allow developers open a solution with older versions of VS (VS2010 SP1 being the oldest version that supports this). There ARE some proyect types that won't be compatible, but from the things you listed, you won't have any problems.

When you open the Solution with newest VS, it WILL make some changes, but you still will be able to open it with VS2010 SP1 (again, with some exceptions).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/visual-studio-project-compatability-and-visualstudioversion.aspx

Anyway, my suggestion is, install VS2013 in a test machine and try it out. You can even create an Azure VM with VS2013 PreInstalled in minutes to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is already available VS2015 preview, why not wait until it is released? (or use the preview)

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx

as other said, it should not brake much