# Common .NET WCF module development

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

I want to create a common web module which act as a service to both .NET desktop application as well as web application (php, asp etc). Its main task is to get the input parameter from client page (can be webpage or desktop app), and do some calculations and provide the output to requested party (webpage/application). I have no experience implementing similar kind of environment and any help will be appreciated. I am using windows server and desktop application is developed in C#. Just wanted to create a common module platform for both environment. Creating a local copy of web hosted module for desktop application is preferred as it act as a copy of web module and only update when the user wants it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommand asmx for webservices anymore, WCF is a better choice by far , you can host it almost anywhere it supports http, tcp or even websockets

Comment: Can you provide me any code samples that meet the above mentioned requirements using WCF.

Comment: where will you host your application , and what protocol do you want to use , http, https, tcp..;etc?

Comment: I will planning to host it under http protocol.

Comment: just follow this tutorial for a simple  application http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566691/WCF-From-a-Beginners-perspective-a-Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your question is actually to create a Web Service here's how you can create a Web Service for visual studio

[Create a asmx web service in C# using visual studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281144/create-a-asmx-web-service-in-visual-studio-2013)

Your web service will have a method that accepts a DataSet to fetch the input of the user from the WebPage/Application(clientside) and will also have a method where it will pass the input it fetched (most appropriate is a DataSet) to the WebPage/Application you want.

P.S.
You need to Add Service Reference to the Project in the ClientSide WebPage/Application

Comment: Than you for your suggestion. But i think WCF is better in terms of providing web services but I have no idea implementing above mentioned service using WCF.

Comment: @sk3145
I can't help you with WCF because I haven't used it before, but with your problem, I was able to do it actually by using Web Service in ASP.Net. The following link might help you with WCF http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139787/What-s-the-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-Services