# How to send a large array into an asmx web service?

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, asmx

I have a web service method definition like so:

```
[WebMethod]
public void UploadFiles(List<FileClass> files)
```

In my client application, I have a large array that I need to pass into the web service like so:

```
client.UploadFiles(fileClassArray);
```

I would not want to use `maxRequestLength`, I've also read about `Buffer.BlockCopy` but I'm having problems with my destination array that could possibly change the web service method definition.

How do I pass this large array into the web service in **chunks**? Or what's the proper way to stream this array?

Comment: You shouldn't use asmx, instead [use WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448472/what-is-the-difference-between-wcf-and-asmx-web-services).

Comment: Yes, but this is part of a legacy code that we should still support.

Comment: The best way to support it would be to rewrite it to a modern framework. You're now adding functionality to code using a framework that was considered to be outdated **five years ago**. Your problem is in part caused by that, actually.

Comment: Yes you are right, but anyway, can you give me a suggestion on the proper way to stream an array?